# Как написать программу, которая бы открывала notepad и запускала бы мой скрипт?

Tags: windows, любой-язык, автоматизация

Вот у меня программа, скажем, notepad и есть некоторый скрипт, или, даже, могу считать это второй программой. Можно ли на каком-нибуди языке написать программу, которая бы открывала notepad и сразу после появления окна этой программы запускала бы мой скрипт (программу). но не раньше появления окна notepad?

Comment: Да, можно. Смотрите темы про автотесты, AutoIt, и т.д.

Comment: Пока остановился на  AutoIt, Скажите еще, а ничего подобного, встроенного в винду, нет?

Comment: Насколько знаю - нету. Попробуйте задать вопрос в чате, вероятно вам нужен какой-то распространенный подход, названия которого вы не знаете.

Comment: А чем чат лучше этого места?

Comment: Тем что комментарии не предназначены для обсуждений, а подобный вопрос скорее всего закроют как "слишком общий или непонятный"

Comment: Пожалуйста, [не стоит](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9364) переписывать и менять вопрос после того, как вам дали ответ, кардинально меняя его суть и задавая новые. [Движок stackoverflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/643) рассчитан на то, что один вопрос - одна тема с ответами; если у вас появился новый вопрос - задайте его в новом топике (при необходимости восстановления контекста - дайте ссылку на предыдущий). Я откатил вопрос к 3 ревизии, если вы планируете создавать новый вопрос то ваши тексты можете найти в [истории правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1012566/revisions)

Comment: В моем понимании я и не менял вопрос: начало-то я вообще не трогал. А в какой-то моей теме мне прямо сказали ее дальнейшее развитие писать в начало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, конечно, и из пушки по воробьям, а можно посмотреть, что умеет `cmd.exe`. Даже не PowerShell...

Итак, сверхзадача: запустить блокнот с файлом `test.cpp`, дождаться, пока окно откроется, запустить `test.bat`. Это делает вот такой, например, файл (с расширением `.bat` или `.cmd`, не суть важно):

```
@echo off
start notepad test.cpp
:loop
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq test.cpp*" | find "notepad"
if errorlevel 1 goto loop
call test.bat
exit
```

*Nostalgie mode on*
Эх, а ведь когда-то под DOS даже игры на bat-файлах были... :)
*Nostalgie mode off*

Comment: С блокнотом все работает. Дальше см. начало.

Comment: А дальше - не пишите `if errorlevel 1 
goto loop` в двух строках, это команда для ОДНОЙ строки - сравните, как у меня, и как у вас...

Comment: И еще - не нужно полностью перекраивать вопрос - лучше задавать новый. А то ведь ерунда получается - как минимум вроде как я отвечаю вам кодом из вашего же вопроса :) Тем более что вопрос у вас стал **совершенно иным**.

Comment: Простите, пожалуйста, **совершенно иным** в чем? В обоих случаях требовалось запустить один файл сразу после всплытия окна другого. Насчет ерунды согласен, но мне до этого в похожей ситуации сказали делать так.

Comment: Вы не видите разницу между "мне нужно решить такую-то задачу" и "что неверно в этом коде"?

Comment: Так а почему меня интересует "что неверно в этом коде"? Потому что "мне нужно решить такую-то задачу", задачу-близнец той задачи, код решения которой мне нужно адаптировать, заменив всего лишь имена используемых приложений для решения моей задачи-близнеца.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97420/discussion-between-mathem-and-harry).