# Может ли точность выполнения батника, зависеть от запускаемого приложения?

Tags: windows, bat, автоматизация

Может ли точность выполнения батника, написанного на основе кода, приведенного Harry в ответе к вопросу [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1012566) темы, зависеть от запускаемого приложения? Попробовал для блокнота - отлично! Для Texmaker - класс! Сделал для прогры, ради которой все затевалось - ни в какую: окно батника закрывается быстрее, чем появляется окно запускаемой из батника программы и все тут!

Comment: Harry, а что вы думаете про такой поворот? Вы это упустили из вида?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что по всей видимости вы запускаете какой то тяжелое ПО, которое в списке процессов появляется раньше, чем показывает своё окно. В вашем случае, очевидно, надо аггрться не на имя процесса, а на что нибудь другое. В идеале нужно искать окно приложения и проверять видимо ли оно.

К сожалению, у меня по рукой сейчас нет windows, поэтому не смогу привести полностью релевантного примера. Но вот пример кода на powershell, который решает [схожую задачу](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cmd-bat/thread1441522.html):

```
# запустим калькулятор
Start-Process calc
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
# узнаем дескриптор окна калькулятора
# можно узнать дескриптор и через FindWindow - но добавить ее прототип через Add-Type у меня не получилось
$hWndAttachTo = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessesByName("calc")[0].MainWindowHandle

# создадим сигнатуру функции  FlashWindow
$signature = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool FlashWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool bInvert);
"@
# добавим ее код в powershell
$FlashWindow = Add-Type -memberDefinition $signature -name "ClassFlashWindow" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru
# заставим окно калькулятора помигать два раза
$bFlashWindow=$FlashWindow::FlashWindow($hWndAttachTo,$true)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$bFlashWindow=$FlashWindow::FlashWindow($hWndAttachTo,$true)
```

Comment: Хочу запустить LyX.

Comment: Sheridan, стоп, так в вашем коде есть *Start-Sleep -Seconds 1*. Это разве не пауза?

Comment: Это пример кода. Можно сделать цикл while, который будет работать пока не появится валидный дескриптор.

Comment: К сожалению, я вас не понимаю. while еще куда ни шло, но *валидный дескриптор*... И Гугл что-то ничего путнего не выдает.

Comment: Надо посмотреть, какой дескриптор вернет `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessesByName("calc")[0].MainWindowHandle` когда calc не запущен. Это - невалидный дескриптор. Это скорее всего будет 0 или -1

Comment: Так: https://i.postimg.cc/BQqV52FT/image.jpg ?